# Live webRTC audio waveform

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am looking to use webRTC to record audio and would like to know if there is a way to have a live waveform as the audio is being captured.

From looking online I found: [this - wavesurfer](http://wavesurfer-js.org)

However this creates a waveform after the audio has been fully loaded.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on wavesurfer.js's Wiki this [microphone plugin](http://www.wavesurfer-js.org/example/microphone) used for realtime visualization of the microphone audio signal.
Also used in [Video.js Record](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record).

Comment: I too saw that but, I meant a waveform that keeps growing as the audio signal comes in. But thanks for the help, I might just ending up using that.

Comment: Noo, Nooo, Take a look at Video.js Record, they have an audio recorder too, and you'll see what you want :)

Comment: Sweet, Video.js looks like what I need. Thanks